# So, what is the rule for this construction

Tags: grammar

In my textbook I learned that when a sentence shall be nominalized, there are these 2 ways.

1. SENTENCE + こと
2. SENTENCE + という + こと

2 is in case a complex sentence shall be nominalized.

In addition, when the to be nominalized sentenced ends with a な adjective, it shall be nominalized this way:
`な adjective + なこと or な adjective + である`

Now, concerning this case, there were 2 examples in the grammar section, one for simple sentence and one for a complex sentence.

simple sentence:

> 世界中でこの漫画が有名な (な/である) こと知っていますか。

complex sentence:

> 日本に来てから、家族はとても大切 (だ/である) ということに初めて気がついた。

Now, for the complex sentence, would it be possible to write ...家族はとても大切**な**ということ... as well?

My textbook gave me no explanation as to why it only proposes the copula, but not the な suffix DESPITE claiming otherwise just a few lines before :/ 
Or is it possible that in the nominalization of complex sentences requiring という, it is obligatory to use the copula when the to be nominalized sentence ends with a な adjective?

Comment: Did you mean to include the な after 有名？  One of the selections there could potentially turn into 有名ななこと、which, imperfect though I am, seems  grammatically incorrect.  I ask because 大切 is also a な-adjective, and I just wanted to clarify your understanding here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically:

> - 連体形(attributive form) + こと
> - 終止形(predicative/terminal form) + ということ

So grammatically speaking you can use...

- 有名な+こと <sub>(有名な is the attributive form)</sub>
- 有名である+こと <sub>(ある is the attributive form)</sub>
- 有名だ+ということ <sub>(有名だ is the terminal form)</sub>
- 有名である+ということ <sub>(ある is the terminal form)</sub>

as in:

> この漫画が有名なことを知っていますか。
>   この漫画が有名であることを知っていますか。
>   この漫画が有名だということを知っていますか。
>   この漫画が有名であるということを知っていますか。

<sub>As an aside, you could also say:

この漫画が有名なのを知っていますか。

この漫画が有名だと知っていますか。

(or この漫画、有名だって知ってる？ in colloquial speech)</sub>

---

> would it be possible to write ...家族はとても大切なということ

No, you can't say な+ということ. 大切な is the attributive form and should usually be followed by a noun, as in 大切なこと, 大切な人.

> in the nominalization of complex sentences requiring という, it is obligatory to use the copula...

Yes, you should use the terminal form 大切だ or 大切である before という.
<sub>(You could also say 「大切ということ」「大切と気づいた」「有名ということ」「有名と」「有名って」 etc., dropping the だ. This might sound a bit informal.)</sub>

So I think you could say...

> 家族はとても大切だということに初めて気がついた。
>   家族はとても大切であるということに初めて気がついた。
>   (? 家族はとても大切なことに初めて気がついた。 *)
>   家族がとても大切であることに初めて気がついた。
>   <sub>Also: 家族はとても大切だと初めて気がついた。
>
>   家族はとても大切であると初めて気がついた。
>
>   (or 家族はとても大切だって、初めて気がついた。 in colloquial speech)</sub>

<sub>*might be a bit strange maybe because it could sound like "Family noticed something important..."</sub>